# Autohotkey Global #IfWinNotExist With Nested #IfWin

Tags: windows, autohotkey

I have a large amount of hotkeys and some of them have #IfWinActive wrapping them, making them context-sensitive to specific windows.

However, I want to wrap the whole AHK script with with an #IfWinNotActive so it doesn't trigger any of the hotkeys in some full-screen apps (AnyDesk and certain games).

It seems to not support that however because the first "#IfWinActive" that it encounters (to reset context sensitivity) resets all context-sensitivity including the #IfWinNotActive at the top of my script that (that I want to be global).

I don't want to Any alternative on how I can set a global context sensitivity another way? I couldn't find anything relevant [in the help](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm).

Comment: You can create a group of the windows you don't want to trigger the context sensitive hotkeys and use `#If WinActive("specific window") && !WinExist("ahk_group certain_games")`. Or create as much groups of those windows (ahk_group certain_games1, ahk_group certain_games2) as your #If WinActive's and add `#IfWinNotExist ahk_group certain_games1` after `#IfWinActive specific window 1` then `#IfWinNotExist ahk_group certain_games2`  after `#IfWinActive specific window 2` etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [groups](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm#ahk_group) and `#If`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm)</sup>, as suggested in the comment by @user3419297, or you can use the regex [title match mode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTitleMatchMode.htm).
Hard to say which would be the better approach. I guess I could argue the regex approach is better, but just because I can't come up with a real downside for it.
With `#If` you could run into its [downsides](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm#General_Remarks), if you have a more complex script. But if your script it just basic hotkeys and and your `#If` conditions are nothing amazing, you're not going to run into the downsides.
Of course with regex the downside could be that you're unfamiliar with regex.

Anyway, here's an example of the regex approach:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, RegEx ;in the auto-execute section

#IfWinActive, ^(?!.+\bStack Overflow\b) ahk_exe ^(?!.+\\(notepad|mygame)\.exe)
1::ToolTip, 1
#IfWinActive, Notepad\+\+
2::ToolTip, 2
#IfWinActive, ^(?!.+\bStack Overflow\b) ahk_exe ^(?!.+\\(notepad|mygame)\.exe)
3::ToolTip, 3
4::ToolTip, 4
#IfWinActive, ^(?!\*?NotThisFile\.txt) ahk_exe notepad\.exe
5::ToolTip, 5
#IfWinActive, ^(?!.+\bStack Overflow\b) ahk_exe ^(?!.+\\(notepad|mygame)\.exe)
6::ToolTip, 6
7::ToolTip, 7
8::ToolTip, 8
#IfWinActive
```

Hotkeys <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd>, <kbd>4</kbd>, <kbd>6</kbd>, <kbd>7</kbd> and <kbd>8</kbd> work everywhere, except in windows that contain the words `Stack Overflow`, or in windows that come from an executable named `notepad.exe` or `mygame.exe`.

Hotkey <kbd>2</kbd> works only in a window, in which the title contains `Notead++`.

Hotkey <kbd>5</kbd> works only in a window, that comes from the executable `notepad.exe` and the window's title does not start with `NotThisFile\.txt` or `*NotThisFile\.txt`.

If you're unfamiliar with regex, or can't understand those specific regexes, [here's](https://regex101.com/) one website that can be of help.
One thing worth mentioning though, that's specific to AHK here, is the usage of `ahk_exe`, `ahk_class`, etc, in a regex title match.
When you use one of these it treats what comes after as separate, which is why e.g. something like this is valid `^something$ ahk_exe ^something\.exe$`.
Also, in regex title match mode, ahk_exe matches against the **full** .exe path. Which is why we need `^.+\\file\.exe` for the negative lookahead.

---

And about the group approach, if you can't figure it out and want to learn it, I can edit it into this answer later.
I'm out of time to write more into this answer right now.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I did, I used the group method and the answer was just to replace all the "#IfWinActive" with the "#IfWinNotExist Group" that I wanted to be applied globally. Worked great for my hotkeys to not trigger work in my specified games and AnyDesk.